# How to inject the value of a Struts <s:property /> tag into another tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, el, taglib, struts-tags

I want to take the value of an attribute in the action class by using Struts2 property tag  `<s:property value="id"/>` and give it to another tag, something like this (wrong code, just to give the idea):

```
<t:tag id="<s:property value="id"/>"/>
```

How can I do this?

Note: `<t:` is mapped to a custom taglibrary.

Comment: what is `<t:` ? Another taglibrary ? Or it's an error and you meant `<s:` ?

Comment: And what can it read ? JSP EL ?

Comment: only a number , am still a new at this

Comment: You are new to this and you write crappy taglibraries ? Just stick with the existing ones, on the shoulders of the giants! If instead you are inheriting it, and you can't drop it... try like in the answer I'll post soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest (server-side) tags like that;

If you don't know exactly what you are doing, I'd suggest to stick with the existing taglibraries, [standing on the shoulders of the giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants); if instead you are inheriting it, and can't drop it, then try with JSP EL syntax:

```xml
<t:tag id="${id}"/>
```

(Objects in the Value Stack are made available to JSP EL by the Struts2 request wrapper)